# jQuery: remove resizable handles on clickout and add them on click in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to to create a simple drag, drop and resize page using jquery.

So far everything works fine. But now I have faced a new challenge.

This is the current process:

1- user drags and drops an image (div) onto a parent DIV.
2- The user will be presented with a clone of the dragged and dropped image with handles so they can easily resize the image (div).

basically, what i need to do is to remove the handles (helper), on `clickout` and add them again if the user wants to resize the DIV and if they `click inside the DIV again`.

so i tried to use this code:

```
$("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").remove();
```

the code above will remove the handles only when a new image has been dragged and dropped onto the stage. also, it is not a good way of doing this becuase it will remove the handles completely and I cannot re-add them again.

This is my entire code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
           google.load("jquery", "1.6.3");
           google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({

        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit'


    });

            $("#droppable").droppable({

                drop: function (e, ui) {

                    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();
                        ui.helper.remove();
                        $("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").remove();

                    x.draggable({

                        //helper: 'original',
                        containment: '#droppable',
                        tolerance: 'fit'


                    });

                    x.resizable({

                      animate: true,
                      //aspectRatio: 16 / 9,

                      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                      handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"



                    });

                    x.appendTo('#droppable');

                }

                }
            });


});
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
.col{
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#col1{
    width:500px;
    height:820px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    float:left;

}

.drag{
    width:100px;

    height:100px;
    position:relative;

    background-size:contain !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;

}
.drag:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */

}

#droppable{
    width:720px;
    height :820px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;

    }


    #droppable .drag{
        width:200px;
        height :220px;
        background-size:200px;
        border:none;


    }

.new-class{

        width:200px;
        height :220px;
        background-size:200px;
        border:solid 4px #666;
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;


}
.ui-resizable-n{
     top: -10px;
    left:50%;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;


}
.ui-resizable-e
{
   right:-10px;
     top:50%;   
        width: 6px;
    height: 6px; 
}
.ui-resizable-s
{
     bottom: -10px;
    left: 50%;
        width:6px;
    height: 6px;
}

.ui-resizable-w
{
     left:-10px;
     top:50%;
        width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}

.ui-resizable-nw
{
     left: -10px;
    top: -10px;    
        width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}
.ui-resizable-ne
{
     top: -10px;
     right: -10px; 
        width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}
.ui-resizable-sw
{
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -10px;
        width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}
.ui-resizable-se
{
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}

.ui-resizable-helper { 
border: 1px dotted #CCC; 
}


     </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center" id="wrapper">

            <div class="col" id ="droppable">
            </div>



                <div class = "col" id="col1">
                <div id="drag1" class="drag" style="background-image:url(images/Chrysanthemum.jpg); background-position:center;"> </div>

                <div id="drag2" class="drag" style="background-image:url(images/Hydrangeas.jpg); background-position:center;" ></div>

               <div id="drag2" class="drag"  style="background-image:url(images/3.jpg); background-position:center;"></div>






            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I do apologies for posting my entire code, I did try to create a working jsfidle and it seems like jsfidle doesn't like jquery.ui URL.

could someone please advise on this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect a click falling outside of a particular element, you can do that by attaching a click handler to a top-level element (commonly `document`) and look at `event.target`.

To reinsert elements you've previously removed from the DOM you have to use `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`. However, a better way to get the same visual effect is to simply use `hide` and `show` which toggle the css property `diplay:`, since you don't have to care about where you need to reinsert the detached elements. It would look like:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    // matches all children of droppable, change selector as needed
    if( $(e.target).is("#droppable *") ) {
        $(e.target).find(".ui-resizable-handle").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That is almost what I was looking for. But the problem with your solution (code) is that it will ADD (show) the `.ui-resizable-handle` for all the images inside the `#droppable` area! is there any way to show the .ui-resizable-handle individually when the .drag has been clicked on? I tried using `this` but that stopped the code working.

Comment: `this` in the above handler will be the top-level element. Try using `$(e.target).find(".ui-resizable-handle").show()`